# Change DateTimePicker time increments from 1 to 5 minutes

Tags: ios, iphone, uidatepicker

How can I change the the minute time increment on `UIDatePicker` from 1 to 5 minutes?

I notice that simply double-tapping on any of the dates or times in the scroll wheel change it from 1 minute to 5 minute increments.How can I achieve this programatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UIDatePicker has a [`minuteInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/minuteInterval). Default is 1, set it to 5.